# C: how to check if two [x][y] co-ords match?

Tags: c, if-statement, coordinates

I am trying to build a maze game with a player @ and two monsters M.

When a monster is on the same coordinate as the player, it should print GAME OVER.

But I only have this working for one of the two monsters.

Why? How do you solve this?

```
void check_and_move(game_object *obj, int xoffset, int yoffset, char *v) {
    game_object *treasure = treasure_position->object;
    game_object *monster = monster_position->object;
    game_object *monster2 = monster_position->object;


    // If player gets eaten by a monster: GAME OVER!
    if(player->x == monster->x) {
        if(player->y == monster->y) {
            printf("GAME OVER!\n");
            free_memory();
        }
    }
    // If player gets eaten by a monster: GAME OVER!
    if(player->x == monster2->x) {
        if(player->y == monster2->y) {
            printf("GAME OVER!\n");
            free_memory();
        }
    }

    // If player coordinate == treasure coordinate: PLAYER WINS!
    if(player->x == treasure->x) {
        if(player->y == treasure->y) {
            printf("You have captured the treasure!\n");
            free_memory();
        }
    }

    // If coordinate is not blocked and can be moved to, object gets moved to it.
    if (isMovable(obj, obj->x + xoffset, obj->y + yoffset)) {
        move_object(obj, obj->x + xoffset, obj->y + yoffset);
    } else {
        *v = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _But I only have this working for one of the two monsters._? You could also do `if (player->x == monster->x && player->y == monster->y) {...`

Comment: Yes that's it: I have only one monster eating the player, the other doesn't.

Comment: So what happens when you run into the second monster?

Comment: Nothing, the monster M displays instead of @, so it's like I'm hiding behind it.

Comment: Does it print `GAME OVER!`?

Comment: @ David Schwartz no it doesn't

Comment: It only prints GAME OVER! when monster1 eats it

Comment: @DavidSchwartz is there a way to check if the coord the player is moving to is 'M'?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
game_object *monster2 = monster_position->object;
```

to:

```
game_object *monster2 = monster2_position->object;
```

Also, change this:

```
// If player gets eaten by a monster: GAME OVER!
if(player->x == monster->x) {
    if(player->y == monster->y) {
        printf("GAME OVER!\n");
        free_memory();
    }
}
```

To this:

```
// If player gets eaten by a monster: GAME OVER!
if ( ((player->x == monster->x) && (player->y == monster->y)) ||
     ((player->x == moster2->x) && (player->y == moster2->y)) )
{
    printf("GAME OVER!\n");
    free_memory();
    return;
}
```

But really, you should clean this logic up. For example, you could implement a helper function like:

```
bool same_position (game_object *o1, game_object *o2)
{
    return (o1->x == o2->x) && (o1->y == o2->yl);
}
```

And then you can write things like this, which are easier to understand:

```
if (same_position(player, monster) || same-position(player, monster2))
```

And the same for seeing if the player has found the treasure.

Comment: Well, I answered the question asked, "*how to check if two [x][y] co-ords match?*", but it's possible there are bugs elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Is there a way to check if the coord the player is going to is 'M'?

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning from the function, hence it's continuing without signaling whether or not the player was eaten. And thus, I suppose continuing with the game even though the game should be over.

You should return from it if `free_memory()` does what I suppose it does, then it should be a problem to countinue with the rest of the function after you call `free_memory()`.

First of all, all the conditions could be combined in a single `if` using `&&` for the `x` and `y` coordiniate of each pair of `monster`/`player` and `||` for the two pairs.

And then you must return from the function after calling `free_memory()`.

```
// If player gets eaten by a monster: GAME OVER!
if (((player->x == monster->x)  && (player->y == monster->y)) ||
    ((player->x == monster2->x)  && (player->y == monster2->y)))
{
    printf("GAME OVER!\n");
    free_memory();
    // Now return from the function
    return;
}
```

Comment: What do I return from what?

Comment: If you want, you could return a value from `check_and_move()` like an `enum` indicating the `check` failed or succeeded to decide whether or not to continue with the game.

Comment: Is there a way to check if the co-ord that the player is going to is 'M'?

Comment: The if condition does that, you are just ignoring the fact that the check gives you as a result that the monster and the player are in the same position.

Comment: void functions should not return anything?!

Comment: @CarolineRudolph Sorry I don't understand your question. Let my try to respond, if the return type is `void` of course you can't return a value. What I suggest is `enum CheckState {NotEaten, Eaten, Other};` and then `enum CheckState check_and_move( ... )` so you can return `Eaten` when the player is eaten and check for that from the caller function.

Comment: I don't think that's going to fix the problem, it might just help with the debugging.

Comment: I'm reading from a .txt file multiple monsters 'M' and I only have one list_node structure. Do I need to make more list nodes?

Comment: You seem to have a lot to do and you don't know how. Please fell free to write to iharob@gmail.com. Tomorrow is sunday and I am free so I can check it. For now it's 23:40 so it's late here in my country and I have to sleep. I want to help you because it seems that your confusion is not your fault and you apparently have the potential.